# SharePoint Online storage quota automation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, quota

Need to know whether we can automate storage quota for an site collection beyond 1TB. I know that Microsoft increased storage quota to 25TB for an site collection.

But if I set below settings to automatic, then will it increase storage quota even after 1TB?

"Site Collection Storage Management
Automatic storage management provides worry free operation by removing the overhead of having to manage individual storage limits. Manual override allows the tenant admin to set usage limits on a per site collection level.

Automatic 
Manual   "

Comment: I wouldn't really do that though, depending on the size of your organization one site collection can eat your entire pooled storage. Just because it supports 25TB doesn't mean you should set them all to automatic.

Comment: As per you comments if I set it to automatic then even after 1TB also the storage quota will still automatically grow up to 25TB?

Comment: It will go up to 25TB or whatever your pooled storage max is. We can't possibly have a 25TB site collection in our tenant as we only have 6TB pooled storage. Just because they can go up to 25TB doesn't mean you get unlimited sites hitting 25TB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set them to be automatic, then yes, your site collections will continue to grow until it hits 25TB or you hit your pooled storage capacity, that little green bar in your admin page.

While it might be easy to fall into the trap of setting things for automatic, it really is a bad practice. A single site collection can burn through all your pooled storage leaving you out of space for everyone else.

Applying sensible quotas gives you control and safe, structured growth instead of making it the wild west. Just because they can go to 25TB doesn't mean they should.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct understanding. You can see this on the SharePoint admin center.
Once you set it automatic then you will not see the storage quota option in ribbon and also gone from the site collections.

but for testing purpose if you turn it manual then in front of site collection you can see the storage limit is 25600Gb which is 25tb.

[image]
Also read this blog post: https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/18/sharepoint-online-simplifies-storage-management/

Comment: I am clear about the view of these options, but I am more concern whether it will increase quota automatically even after 1TB of an site collection? If this set as automatic.

Comment: Yes it will here is statement from the blog i mentioned ". Your site collections only use what they need from the available pooled storage, automatically, up to whatever the current maximum system limit is per site collection"